# Creating Bezier Polygons (Spline Polygons) using Survey123 for Arboriculture Surveys

Tags: javascript, arcgis-survey123

I’m working on a Survey123 survey to capture the tree canopy based on the centroid (Lat, Long), Norh, South, East and West distances in meters. The idea is the mobile worker locates a point in the map and add the other fours readings manually (N,S, E, W) in meters and Survey123 would create a Bezier polygon (spline polygon) based on the readings.

After doing some research, I think this could be possible by using JavaScript functions in Survey123 connect app. Some examples can be found here: https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-survey123-blog/extending-survey123-smart-forms-with-custom-js/b...

The ConvexHull example (script attached for reference) could be a good starting point to modify the code but I’m after a Bezier polygon instead of ConvexHull,

Below an example of the ConvexHull javascript example by ESRI:

[image]

Below an example of spline curve (not closed) although my aim is having a close smooth polygon:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Code for ConvexHull to be modify:

```
// Compare points - first by x, then by y if x is identical
function comparePoint(a, b) {
    if (a.x < b.x)
        return -1;
    else if (a.x > b.x)
        return +1;
    else if (a.y < b.y)
        return -1;
    else if (a.y > b.y)
        return +1;
    else
        return 0;
};

// Create a convex hull for a sorted set of points
function makeHullPresorted(points) {
    if (points.length <= 1)
        return points.slice();
    
    // Andrew's monotone chain algorithm. Positive y coordinates correspond to "up"
    // as per the mathematical convention, instead of "down" as per the computer
    // graphics convention. This doesn't affect the correctness of the result.
    
    var upperHull = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        var p = points[i];
        while (upperHull.length >= 2) {
            var q = upperHull[upperHull.length - 1];
            var r = upperHull[upperHull.length - 2];
            if ((q.x - r.x) * (p.y - r.y) >= (q.y - r.y) * (p.x - r.x))
                upperHull.pop();
            else
                break;
        }
        upperHull.push(p);
    }
    upperHull.pop();
    
    var lowerHull = [];
    for (var i = points.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var p = points[i];
        while (lowerHull.length >= 2) {
            var q = lowerHull[lowerHull.length - 1];
            var r = lowerHull[lowerHull.length - 2];
            if ((q.x - r.x) * (p.y - r.y) >= (q.y - r.y) * (p.x - r.x))
                lowerHull.pop();
            else
                break;
        }
        lowerHull.push(p);
    }
    lowerHull.pop();
    
    if (upperHull.length == 1 && lowerHull.length == 1 && upperHull[0].x == lowerHull[0].x && upperHull[0].y == lowerHull[0].y)
        return upperHull;
    else
        return upperHull.concat(lowerHull);
};

// Returns a new array of points representing the convex hull of
// the given set of points. The convex hull excludes collinear points.
// This algorithm runs in O(n log n) time.  
// Returns the convex hull, assuming that each points[i] <= points[i + 1]. Runs in O(n) time.
function convexHull(points) {
//  console.log(arguments.callee.name, "points:", JSON.stringify(points));

    if (!Array.isArray(points)) {
        return [];
    }

    var newPoints = points.slice();
    newPoints.sort(comparePoint);
    return makeHullPresorted(newPoints);
};
```